# Is there a way to use background image with scaling and max-width?

Tags: css, background-image

I'm trying to creat a simple layout with CSS and HTML.

Is it possible that the background image of the body tag scale to 100% of the width and height if the dimensions of the screen are smaller than the image size, and if it the screen is larger, then the image should be shown without scaling/stretching (i.e. at 100%)?

How can I do this with CSS?

I have looked at the question: [Possible to set a max-width for a background image? (want to scale background-image down, but not scale up)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980342/possible-to-set-a-max-width-for-a-background-image-want-to-scale-background-im)

But that doesn't seem to be working for body tag, & I can't get it to scale when the Windows size is smaller than the image.
This is the simplified code I'm using:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<div id="bgroud">
</div>

</BODY>
</HTML>

body, html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }

    #bgroud {
        background: url("index.jpg") no-repeat fixed left top transparent;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-size:cover; 
        max-width:1280px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you,

```
 background-size:cover; // or 100%
```

Comment: When I use this, the image does scale when the window is smaller, but now if the window is larger than the image, the image scales, but is then cut off. I've added my code to the question.

Comment: adjust the width of container." cover " property takes full width of container and it will stearch thw bg-size

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand what you are trying to tell me. Can you expand your answer with more code, so will illustrates it?

Comment: can you provide me the link.

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS is working for me:

```
body, html{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}


#bgroud {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image:url("index.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left top;
    overflow:  auto;
    background-size:cover;
    max-width:1280px;
    max-height:902px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, hope it'll work :)

```
body {
    background-image:  url("/assets/pic.jpg");
    background-size:   cover;   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    max-width:100%;
}
```