# How do I have a background-image only scale down to fit its element, but not scale up?

Tags: css, background-image, scale, background-size

The div in which I have a background image is of unknown size. It can be 16px high, it can be 1600px, and anything in between. There's a background-image in there that's roughly 440px wide and 250px high.

When the div is higher than 250px, the background image doesn't scale. That's desired behaviour. So far so good.

If the div gets under 250px in height, the background-image is clipped. That's unwanted: I want it to scale to the div's smaller height.

How do I use css (or, if not possible, js) to have a background-image scale down when it doesn't fit its div, but never scale up when the div is bigger than itself? Essentially, I want to use `background-size: contain;`, but with a max set to the image's height.

I tried all kinds of cover and contains, but none have the desired effect.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980342/possible-to-set-a-max-width-for-a-background-image-want-to-scale-background-im) does not help either, for I cannot set a max-height on the div. It contains content added by the site's editor. If that's a lot, all of it must show.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bakabaka/2zetkrg0/

Comment: could you show some code example. I understand your request but find it hard to approach a solution without seeing the/a code example. Cheers

Comment: I suspect maybe you would have to contain the background image it its own element/div and set that element in CSS as having a max-size or being `background-size:contain;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is simply inserting an `img` inside the element you wanted to give a background to an option?

You can use `max-width:100%; max-height:100%;` on the image, so it will not exceed the container dimensions, but will still retain its aspect ratio and won't grow larger than its original size. Next, you could position the image absolutely and give it `z-index:-1` so it'll be behind all the content and won't be affected by it. Finally, just give the image `top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(50%,50%);` if you want it centered within its container.

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/9dnqd6bc/1/

You could even set `min-width` and `min-height`, if you wanted to have a minimum size for the background.

Comment: That's going to be my fallback if it turns out it doesn't work with pure css. Thanks!

Comment: I did try `div::before{content:url(background.jpg);` first, but unfortunetly I couldn't figure out a way to control its dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it'll work :)

```
container{
    background-image:  url("/assets/pic.jpg");
    background-size:   cover;   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    max-height:250px;
}
```